# Pydantic ValidationError for inheritance(nested) model

Tags: python, django, pydantic

There is a structure to models with inheritance

```
class CampaignAdditionalData(BaseModel):
    campaigns: List[CampaignData]
    stages: List[CreativeUsageStage]
    language_mode: ReplicationLanguageMode
    creative_rotation_type: CreativeRotationType

class CampaignData(BaseModel):
    title: NonEmptyString
    geo_segment: NonEmptyString
    ac_type: ACType
    conversion: Conversion
    asset_type: GoogleCampaignAssetType
    date: datetime.date
    name: NonEmptyString
    budget: PositiveDecimal
    cpa: PositiveDecimal
```

This is how the code calls for the processing of incoming parameters

```
from pydantic import ValidationError, parse_obj_as

        def check_campaigns_data(request: HttpRequest) -> JsonResponse:
            data = json.loads(request.body.decode('utf-8'))
            try:
                campaign_data = parse_obj_as(CampaignAdditionalData, data)
            except ValidationError as e:
                response = {'status': 'validation_error', 'errors': e.errors()}
                return JsonResponse(response)
            .....
            ....
```

If an exception occurs, e.g. in the `geo_segment` field in the `CampaignData` the command
`print(response)` inside except block return

```
    {
'status': 'validation_error', 
'errors': [{'loc': ('__root__', 'campaigns', 0, '__root__'), 
'msg': 'No such geo segment found', 
'type': 'assertion_error'}]
}
```

From this you can see that the pydantic ValidationError returns the field `campaigns` of the general `CampaignAdditionalData` model as `loc` value

```
('__root__', 'campaigns', 0, '__root__')
```

Is there any way to get the name of the `geo_segment` field in the error message, i.e. go even lower in the field hierarchy?